# Django - What is faster between Filter() and All()

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two queries:

```
query1 = MyObject.objects.all()

query2 = MyObject.objects.filter(my_filter=my_value)
```

What is faster between query1 and query2, and why ?

Also I am using PostgreSQL for my database.

Comment: If you want to know which horse is faster, race them.

Comment: I especially want to know why one is faster than the other.

Comment: @KlausD Fantastic suggestion in the whole  Stack over flow community.